# Exporting models from SceneKit to Blender

Tags: ios, blender, scenekit

I am trying to export models from Blender to SceneKit.  I can export the basic geometry.  However, I cannot export the images that I painted on the surfaces.  Can someone tell me how to get the images moved over to the .scnassets folder of SceneKit?

Comment: So these are the texture maps you authored somewhere else (like Substance Painter or Quixel Suite)?